# SpringJSFLogin The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring, maven, jsf-2

After adding new dependency in Maven and namespaces for omniFaces, my Spring Web Project (all pages) rejected to start. I haven't made any alterations in web.xml, however, TomCat 8.0 informs me that "The requested resource is not available".
I use JSF 2.0 and all my pages are .xhtml which are stored in src/main/webapp folder.
Maven update, clean and install didn't have any result.
Creation of appropriate SpringJSFLogin folder in src/main didn't help.

The problem turned out to be **related with omniFaces** library - somewhy it requires special attitude. I would be grateful if someone can explain my how to resolve this peculiarity.

Thanks in advance.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>SpringJSFHello</display-name>

   <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Main.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Spring listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Start JSF -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- JSF URL mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>   
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter    
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Namespaces of Administrator-AddDish.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
```

[Screenshot of error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Hgh.png)

Comment: Somewhy omniFaces library requires special attitude and throws 404 above mentioned exception. Thus, the question is not actual anymore.         --------------------------------Anyway, I would be grateful if someone can explain what I should do to resolve it since I need omniFaces in my app.

Comment: Which OmniFaces version? Did you read webapp's startup log for clues?

Comment: Thanks for response. OmniFaces version is 2.2. Frankly saying I am newbie to loggin, so I have no idea where to find them. I added dependencies for log4j, however I amn't sure, that it writes data to the file.

Comment: OmniFaces 2.2 requires CDI and JSF 2.2 and Servlet 3.0. You're however using Tomcat (which by default doesn't have CDI, instead you're using Spring for some reason) , and JSF 2.0 and your web.xml is declared conform Servlet 2.5 (even though Tomcat 8 is Servlet 3.1 compatible). Try OmniFaces 1.12 instead if you don't need CDI features nor OmniFaces 2.x specific things.